# Dance: tango argentino dance floor dimension

Tags: dance

what are the approximate minimum dance floor dimensions to dance tango argentino? I need it for a project of tango argentino-themed restaurant/club.

Comment: Hi - although we should be able to answer questions about tango music here, and maybe even about the crossover of the music and the dance, this question doesn't seem to have a musical aspect.

Comment: I'd be grateful for the answer on my question as I cant find any information about it and I thought this is the best place to find it :) If you cant really help me with it, could you tell me where should i look for ?

Comment: Have you tried asking on a dance forum?

Comment: Yes i tried on dance-forum.com , but the registration there is broken and I really need an answer, thats why i decided to ask for it here.

Comment: How about https://www.reddit.com/r/tango/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/Dance/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much depends on the number of people you want to accommodate.  Tango Argentino is a slowish dance with moderate progression and room coverage, so you can get away with quite a bit less than the "120m² per 6 dance pairs" requirement I seem to remember from ballroom dancing tournaments.  But a tango argentino-themed restaurant/club will most certainly also want to accommodate milongas and tango waltz.  What does "themed" mean?  Do you only want enough room for show dancing, or are the patrons themselves permitted to dance?

How about contacting some of your prospective customers and ask them what made them pick their favorite locations so far?  You'll want to accommodate them in more respects than just floor area anyway.